# How to add a row dynamically to a table using javascript onBlur or onkeypress event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement where i need to add rows dynamically to a table. Onclick on the "Try it" button works correctly but as per the requirement, I need to call the Javascript event on click of anywhere on the screen so i have used on blur event but its not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
        
        }
```

```css
table, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<body onblur="myFunction()">
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Row1 cell1</td>
        <td>Row1 cell2</td>
      </tr>
      
    </table>
    <br>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button><br>
    </body>
```

The above snippet works for onclick function, but i want to add a row dynamically when i click anywhere on the screen or just by pressing any key in the keyboard.

Comment: Try changing `onBlur` to `onClick`. This adds a new row when you click anywhere on the body.

Answer (score 0):

like Alex W. said, just use `onClick()` on the body but be sure to load in the javascript before the body.

To check for key presses you could use

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    var key_code = event.keyCode;
    if (key_code === 38) {
        alert('test);
    } 
});
```